# VcXsrv on Windows 10 wsl2 does not show app

Tags: windows-10, xorg, wsl2

I have gone through many posts after googling this and I do not see an answer or an answer that works.

I am on Windows 10 (NOT Windows 11)
I have Debian 11 on WSL2.

I have VcXsrv installed, latest at the time of this writing.

I have tried many of the options in VcXsrv including disabling security but to no avail.

So here is what happens.

I have DISPLAY set to 172.20.144.1:0, my ip for WSL is 172.20.144.134/20 and I ran this command to get 172.20.144.1.

`echo $(grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}')`

I have tried other 1 liners but this one got me the most success.

So after this I type:

`xeyes`

which is installed.  And it just sits there, it does not display.

The other one liners and DISPLAYS that I have tried say Error cannot open display.

Is there any hope?

Thanx

Comment: Have you opened a firewall port?  See [this blog post](https://skeptric.com/wsl2-xserver/), which has some of the best advice I've seen for how to do it (including limiting the scope, which most instructions skip over).

Comment: Thank you.  The firewall was the issue.